# Can't understand example using continuations

Tags: scheme, continuation

I'm reading the [r6rs Scheme report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs.pdf) and am confused by the explanation of continuations (I find it to be too dense and lacking of examples for a beginner).

What is this code doing and how does it evaluate to 4?  Why does `call/cc` want an argument that's a function of one argument?  How is `call/cc`'s argument used?

```
(+ 1 (call-with-current-continuation
       (lambda (escape)
         (+ 2 (escape 3)))))
          =⇒ 4
```

This example is from section 1.11 - Continuations.

Comment: This should be a perfect question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No it isn't:  according to [their FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), this question fails a ton of the eligibility criteria ...

Comment: Definitely not a Code Review question - example code; he's going for understanding, not betterment, wasn't written himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`call/cc` takes a function with one argument, because that argument will be populated with the "current continuation". The continuation in this case will return to the point "just after" the `call/cc`, namely where its return value is being set.

Thus, when you call `(escape 3)`, the rest of the expression (the `(+ 2 ...)`) is abandoned, and 3 is set as the return value of the `call/cc`. Thus, the `(+ 1 (call/cc ...))` is now evaluated as `(+ 1 3)`, hence the result is 4.

Answer (score 1):

Chris' answer is great, but now that I've figured it out I'd like to add a bit more explanation from the perspective of a beginner to continuations.

### call/cc examples

I've done `(define call/cc call-with-current-continuation)` and will use `hop` (in the manner of "The Seasoned Schemer") to represent the continuation.

ignoring the parameter:  normal evaluation

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (hop)
    (+ 2 3)))
=> 5
```

hopping the entire expression:  also normal evaluation

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (hop)
    (hop (+ 2 3))))
=> 5
```

hopping the operator:

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (hop)
    ((hop +) 2 3))))
=> #<procedure:+>
```

hopping an operand:

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (hop)
    (+ 2 (hop 3))))
=> 3
```

hopping the hopper:

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (hop)
    (hop hop)))
=> #<continuation>
```

Basically, using `call/cc` gives us a way to 'hop' out of an expression, immediately aborting the computation with the specified return value.

*There are many more sophisticated ways to use `call/cc` that I don't understand, but they're not relevant to the OP.*

Answer (score 0):

[This introduction with a lots of examples](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/) helped me understand continuations.

Anyway. These are some examples on how to (ab)use continuations:

```
(define (pair-up x)
    (call/cc (lambda (continuation)
        ;; recursive helper functions
        (define (pair-up-aux x)
        (if (null? x) 
            '()
            (if (null? (cdr x))
                (continuation #f) ; cancel everything and return #f
                (cons (cons (car x) (cadr x)) (pair-up-aux (cddr x)))))) ; build result
        (pair-up-aux x))))
```

This code takes a list and makes a list of pairs such that (pair-up '(a b c d)) becomes ((a . b) (c . d)). It does so by recursing and chaining conses. When I'm at the end of the list and see that i lack one element to create the last pair I would want to cancel everything and return #f instead. If I did (pair-up '(a b c)) and just returned #f I would have got ((a . b) . #f). The call/cc at the moment gives me chance to change my mind and return something else alltogether even though I have started constructing my return. (continuation #f) returns #f as the result of this procedure since the call/cc is around the functions body. The next example implements a loop with continuations.

```
(let ((x 0))
    (let ((cont (call/cc (lambda (x) (x x)))))
        (set! x (+ x 1))
        (display x)
        (newline)
        (if (= x 10)
            (display "Finished!\n")
            (cont cont))))
```

Now this one actually prints 1..10 and calling the continuation will make it do the body of the let several times. I had to use two separate let (or let*) or else x would have been initialized at each run to and x would never ever become 10.